# Excel - How To Highlighting A Whole Column Based on Current Week

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel doc that breaks down various tasks based on the weeks commenced:

I'm trying to highlight the whole column depending on the week we're sitting on (based on the start of the week being a Monday), so that whoever opens the document, whenever, can see clearly straight away what is due to be carried out in that week.

If I focus on the current day then I can highlight the column through a code found on another question ie =L$6=TODAY but I'm looking to focus on the week commencing rather than the day we're sitting on.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Are you describing a Gantt chart?  I found an excellent one here that does conditional formatting based on the dates entered: https://templates.office.com/en-us/simple-gantt-chart-tm16400962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

`=L$6=(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2)+1)`

If you are interested in the days of the next week to the present day, beginning on Monday (2).

Hope it helps